# Javascript/HTML Form field naming issue

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, field

Consider the following simple form:

```
<form method="GET" action="handle.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="search">
</form>
```

Form submission is performed by Javascript (iui) in an ajax call. All fields are properly gathered from the form. Javascript then wants to send the ajax call to "**form.action**".

This is where my problem starts. The object **form** is of type HTMLFormElement. The **action** property of the form is supposed to be of type string and should contain "handle.php". After some hours of debugging, I noticed that form.action is now of type HTMLInputElement.

My question:
Is this proper Javascript behavior? I would have never though that defining a form field with the name of a form attribute, this would happen. In the mean time I solved the issue by naming my field differently.

Thanks in advance for any advice...

---

Found an easy way of displaying my problem. First the form with the problem:

```
<form action="test.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="test">
    <input type="button" onclick="alert(this.form.action);">
</form>
```

And the form that is proper:

```
<form action="test.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="NOT_AN_ATTRIBUTE_NAME" value="test">
    <input type="button" onclick="alert(this.form.action);">
</form>
```

In the first, the popup states "[object HTMLInputElement]", in the second: "http://localhost/test.php".

Comment: Could you please add the javascript code as well

Comment: I dont know is that proper for JS but it seem its in a way you described, is that big issue to change input name from action to another name?

Comment: @Chris: obviously I already solved it by renaming my field. But the problem remains when posting forms using javascript in ajax calls. Form fields cannot have the same name as form attributes.

Comment: Can't you use document.getElementById('formid').getAttribute('action') instead of just form.action? And similarly for other fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you're seeing is because forms are special in JavaScript. All their fields are accessable as properties, so when you use `this.form.action`, it's getting the *field* action, not the HTML attribute `action="test.php"`.

Try changing  `alert(this.form.action);` to `alert(this.form.getAttribute('action'))` instead.

Comment: /Matthew: getAttribute seems to work. It doesn't give a full URL like this.form.action does, but luckily ajax doesn't care too much.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as bug. Maybe there should be an array for 'action '

```
<form action="test.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="test">
    <input type="button" onclick="alert(this.form.action[0]);"> //the form action
    <input type="button" onclick="alert(this.form.action[1]);"> // the text input 
</form>
```

Comment: @Matt: Yes, its proposition to solution that would had to be included in Javascript itself.

Answer (score 0):

your `this.form.action` is still a object. instead of using `alert` put it in a `console.log(this.form.action)` and use firebug and firequery try to discover what events/properties your `this.form.action` has.

!you need to enable your console in firebug before you can use console.log